# It is ok to have a @types library as normal dependency in package.json in a Typescript lib?

Tags: typescript, npm, types, dependencies

...if the library is supposed to be also used by Typescript projects?

I'm making a Typescript library that uses `node-fetch` and `@types/node-fetch`, and I'm publishing the library into a company internal NPM.

If I only declare `@types/node-fetch` as a dev-dependency then later the users of the library (also using Typescript in their projects) will need to install manually the missing types since dev-dependencies are not propagated.

So far the only solution I found is to declare `@types/node-fetch` as a normal dependency, but somehow it feels very wrong (since normally types should not be needed for "runtime").

Is that approach correct? or it is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It is right to declare `@types/node-fetch` as a normal dependency if your public API depends on declarations from `@types/node-fetch`.  See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81).